# How do I set a variable as the user id

Tags: tcsh

I want to write a start up script in tsch that creates a directory some where named with the current user id. I was hoping the following would work.

```
Set A = (id -u -n)
```

But I'm not sure how to handle the output of the command id properly for this kind of variable assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, you use this instead:

```
set A=`id -u -n`
```

The ` characters tell tcsh to run the command and then set assigns the output to A. 
You can make that variable read only too, with:

```
set -r A=`id -u -n`
```

After doing so, attempting to override its value will give:

```
> set A=foo
set: $A is read-only.
```